# How to set timeout while creating WCF proxy using ChannelFactory?

Tags: c#, wcf

I am creating WCF proxy using channel factory, as shown in below -

```
BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
    binding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 20, 0);
    binding.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 20, 0);
    binding.OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 20, 0);
    binding.CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 20, 0);
    binding.BypassProxyOnLocal = bypassProxyOnLocal;
    binding.HostNameComparisonMode = (HostNameComparisonMode)Enum.Parse(typeof(HostNameComparisonMode), hostNameComparisonMode, true);
    binding.MaxBufferPoolSize = maxBufferPoolSize;
    binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = maxReceivedMessageSize;
    binding.MessageEncoding = (WSMessageEncoding)Enum.Parse(typeof(WSMessageEncoding), messageEncoding, true);
    binding.TextEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
    binding.UseDefaultWebProxy = useDefaultWebProxy;
    binding.AllowCookies = allowCookies;
    binding.Security.Transport.Realm = securityTransportRealm;
    binding.Security.Message.AlgorithmSuite = SecurityAlgorithmSuite.Default;
    EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(endPoint);
    ChannelFactory<T> channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<T>(binding, endpointAddress);
    return channelFactory.CreateChannel();
```

This is a generic method to generate proxy of WCF. I have set Timeouts = 20 as shown above in code but still it is throwing error -

```
Error. \nThe request channel timed out while waiting for a reply after 00:00:59.9843997. Increase the timeout value passed to the call to Request or increase the SendTimeout value on the Binding. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.\n

Server stack trace: 

   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)

   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)

   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)

   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
```

Please suggest, how can I fix this?

Comment: The timeout has to be set at both sides of the wire. Do you have control on the WCF service side?

Comment: Yes, I have control. How to set timeout in WCF service side in this case ?

Comment: Are you configuring the service via code or via XML configuration? Can you show the relevant parts?